# How to use update file for McAfee?

Tags: updates, anti-virus

My organization has a huge LAN and my team has a VLAN. The VLAN consists of 15 PC's. None of the VLAN PC can see the outside world. This was designed to isolate those PC's. Each PC on VLAN has McAfee anti-virus software installed.

It's scheduled to do a Full scan weekly but since it does not have access to corporate location where update file is located it can't use latest file definition.

I do have open port to some share drive which is accessible from VLAN and my plan is get this updated file and then update each PC inside VLAN pointing to that shared location.

My question: assuming I'll get this update file (I'm planning to request IT to put it on that shared accessible place ), how could I update my local McAfee software by pointing to update file? I mean does it have any API I could use for it or I could configure my McAfee software to start update using that file by reconfiguration or etc? Thanks for any advice

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Can you indicate the version of McAfee Antivirus you're running as well as the OS on the involved computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you'll have access to McAfee's [standalone virus definitions](http://www.mcafee.com/apps/downloads/security-updates/security-updates.aspx) DAT update, it will be an **.EXE** file that you will simply run on the workstation to be updated.

If you're using the McAfee SuperDAT definitions you can script installation of the DATs using these [command line switches](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB52933)):

```
/LOGFILE     Logs the status into specified file. 
/SILENT      Runs this utility in silent mode. 
/REBOOT      Reboots the machine, if required. 
/PROMPT      Displays the prompt dialog before reboot. 
/E           Extracts packaged files. 
/V           Displays SuperDAT package information. 
/F           Force update of existing version. 
/ENGINEALL   Deploy command-line scanner components.
```

You likely need to use the `/SILENT` switch.

Comment: The version is McAfee VirusScan Engine 8.7 i and I already tried and succeeded by downloading .zip file. Then based on instruction I unzipped it and copied 3 files into McAfee\Engine directory. It worked fine but I still have 2 questions: 1. Which method is better I.e. .exe or .zip and 2. Could I do this from command line because I want it update file at night by scheduled job. Thanks for your reply

Comment: In terms of achieving the desired result of the virus definitions *getting updated* .EXE and .ZIP are not "better" one over the other. However, in terms of which would be easier to *distribute to multiple machines* I think the .ZIP file would be easier.  I would unzip the .ZIP on one machine, then use a script to copy the unzipped files to the `\McAfee\Engine` folder on each of the destination machines.  All you'd need is remote access to that folder form the machine where you unzipped the .ZIP, and that's where you'd run your nightly scheduled script.

Comment: - Twisty, thank for you advice, I'm planning to follow your recommendation and use .zip BUT my problem is that I have 20 PC's and I don't want to replace new files in \McAfee\Engine on each machine. I'd like to do it on one shared place accessible for each PC's and then point from each PC to that place. Do you think it's feasible to scan from local machine but point to one centralized place? It would be much easier for me. Any idea?

Comment: No, you must place the DAT files on each machine individually.  The McAfee antivirus software is hard-coded to look in their own directory for the definition files and will not look elsewhere.  Besides, pointing the antivirus software to look at a network location would create serious system instability while the machine is starting up or at other times it didn't have network connectivity because the antivirus software, which is invoked for all file operations, wouldn't be able to function and in turn would block file operations. That would be a mess.

Comment: Hi again, I did one experiment and wanted to ask your opinion again: 1. I downloaded latest 7602xdat.exe and placed it on a shared folder.
2. From target PC I executed this file. It started McAfee SuperDAT wizard.I completed the wizard and it resulted in updating files in \McAfee\Engine folder.
3. I was able to do a scan with a new DAT
I assume to do the following: 1. schedule a script to download .exe 2. schedule a script on target PC to run that .exe 3. schedule scan after 2. completed. My questions:A. could I execute Wizard from command line B. Does this design make sense for you? Thanks

Comment: As long as you execute the SuperDAT executable with the correct command line switches to operate in silent mode (namely the `/SILENT` switch) you should be fine.  I've edited my answer to include some details about executing the SuperDAT from a script.